# Script if ping fails, output to log

Tags: time, echo, ping

I am trying to find when my internet connection drops during the night. I was reading on other posts a possible solution. Where you can see the time, however there is a limit of 10 hops.

@echo off

set Address=google.com

:Loop

PING -n 5 127.0.0.1>nul

echo Pinging %Address%

%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop

echo Trace route %Address% at %date% %time% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log
tracert %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log

goto Loop

Basically I would like to increase this unlimited, is this possible?
Is there another way to know thru this, when my connection dropped?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change maximum number of hops with -h switch. Set it to bigger number like 100.

Comment: Like this?

@echo off
set Address=google.com
:Loop
PING -n 30 -h 100 127.0.0.1>nul

Comment: More like :

@echo off

set Address=google.com

:Loop

PING -n 5 127.0.0.1>nul

echo Pinging %Address%

%SystemRoot%\system32\ping.exe -n 1 %Address% | %SystemRoot%\system32\find.exe "TTL=" > NUL >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :Loop

echo Trace route %Address% at %date% %time% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log tracert **-h 100**  %Address% >> C:\pingtest\logfile.log

goto Loop